# GIT_COMMIT blank when using azure webhook

Tags: jenkins

I have set up a generic webhook in Azure Devops. The POST command shows that commitId is sent.

```
commits:[{"commitId": "numhere",
```

But when I use $GIT_COMMIT in my jenkins job it is null.

I need to access this to be able post back saying build success/failed.

I am using the generic webhook as I will be sending it via Lamba eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the generic webhook trigger plugin.

Then I used multibranch, made a Jenkinsfile and added the a variable to use in jenkins called gitid

```
  genericVariables: [
   [key: 'gitid', value: '$.resource.commits[0].commitId']
  ],
```